# Coq code in LaTeX using lstcoq does not work

Tags: latex, coq

I want to format Coq code using the LaTeX package "lstcoq.sty". It used to work for me a few years ago, but now I get an error message when trying to use it again. The Coq code inserted in the LaTeX file is:

```
\begin{coq}
Section example.
Variables A B: Type.
Definition pair:Type:=(A*B).
End example.
\end{coq}
```

It produces the following error message:

```
 ! Argument of � has an extra }.
<inserted text>
                \par
l.155 End
          example.
? h
I've run across a `}' that doesn't seem to match anything.
For example, `\def\a#1{...}' and `\a}' would produce
this error. If you simply proceed now, the `\par' that
I've just inserted will cause me to report a runaway
argument that might be the root of the problem. But if
your `}' was spurious, just type `2' and it will go away.
Dows any body know why and how to fix it?
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Solved. I am using Notepad++ which, for some reason, showed "UTF-8" as the encoding for file "lstcoq.sty". Just in case, I changed the encoding to ANSI and then back to UTF-8. Now it works. Has to do with Notepad++ then, not latex nor the package.

Comment: Can you add the information about the OS on which this is running?

Comment: Sure. I am using Windows 10 and the Notepad++ version is 8.5.3 (64 bit).